# Reducer not working for hive

Tags: hbase, hive

I am using cdh3u5 tarballs. I have created Hive external table to query Hbase.I am able to do simple select query like.

```
select * from hbase_tab;
```

But when a query uses mapper and reducer it is failing. Here is what I am getting.

```
hive> select count(*) from hbase_tab;
                                                                                                                           Total MapReduce jobs = 1
    Launching Job 1 out of 1
    Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
    In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
      set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
    In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
      set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
    In order to set a constant number of reducers:
      set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
    Starting Job = job_201211121409_0030, Tracking URL = http://10.3.3.333:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201211121409_030
    Kill Command = /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.3.3.333:9001 -kill job_201211121409_030
    2012-11-21 10:19:28,150 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    2012-11-21 10:20:03,564 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
    Ended Job = job_201211121409_0030 with errors
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

I have tried this giving some numbers in `number` field.

```
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
```

But then also I am facing the same problem. Please guide me as I am new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me what is present in your logs?? Need detailed error

Comment: Thanks nicole the problem is solved now.Thanks again.